# I want to call webservice first then generates table view in iphone

Tags: iphone

I wanted to call webservice first then generates table view, How I can achieve this please help me.

Comment: what you did so far? pls share some code. are you using array to populate your data or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call the web service, and when it ends loading, put the responsed objects in an array, and pass back to the class from where service was called, replace the objects array with your data source array and call [tablview reloadData];

Comment: data source array mean the array from which you will show the data to tableview cells

Answer (score 0):

For this to work can do the following:

At first create a property inside your viewcontroller, which will hold the data you will receive from your webservice, like this:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutabledata *theData;
```

Then synthesize it in your implementation file, using

```
@synthesize theData = _theData;
```

Next you need to set up an NSURLConnection, which will actually load the data from your webservice:

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://thisisyourwebservice.com/somethinghere"];
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

You can set this up inside your viewDidLoad method, or inside a custom setup method. If you want this connection to be cancelable, like when someone dismisses your view, you need to add a property for it like you would do for the data.

So far this is going to create a connection, which will automatically start to download your data from the given URL. But at the moment your data will go nowhere, since you didn't implement the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate Protocol yet. You do this as follows:

Inside your header file do something like the following:

```
@implementation YourViewControllerClass : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
```

Now you need to implement some delegate methods inside your viewcontroller, so you can actually receive data and store it for later use. Those would be:

```
/* you received a response, so now initialize the NSMutableData object */
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    /* this should work in ARC, without ARC you would have to add autorelease after init, else you will have a leak */
    self.theData = [NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

/* here you will actually receive data  */
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.theData appendData:data];
}

/* now your connection has finished loading */
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    /* depending on what you are loading, you need to convert your data into an object
    you of your choice. if you loaded JSON, then use one of the JSONparsers like
   SBJSON, JSONKit or the NSJSONSerialization class available since iOS 5.0.

    After converting your data to the expected object type you will assign it to the
    property which you are using as datasource for your tableView.
   */
}
```

Now, after the connection has loaded you actually should have a property with your desired data inside your viewcontroller. Now just reload your tableView using `[yourTableView reloadeData]` and your should be good to go!